# exchange 2013 receives email but doesn't deliver it

Tags: exchange-2013

We have a single exchange 2013 server. Recently a user has said that emails are being sent to them from external addresses but not arriving.

Having a look at the Message Tracking Log (`Get-MessageTrackingLog - ResultSize Unlimited -Start "nov 9 2013" -End "nov 11 2013" | Out-GridView`) shows that the message was received by the server (there is a SEND event, Source=SMTP from the email address in question) but there was no DELIVER event for that email.

I can find 2 occasions in the last couple of days where this has happened, with two separate senders (same recipient).

What else should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the email. It was delivered to SpamQuarantine Mailbox, not to the user. It was in the transport log and appeared as being sent from postmaster@domain.com to junk@domain.com instead of the original from/to

Comment: As an aside there should always be an EventId associated with the message, which should give you a clue as to the disposition of the email.

Comment: @slm, I was the author and answered my own question. The solution was that the spam filter had redirected the email to the SpamQuarantine Mailbox. I couldn't find it in the Get-MessageTrackingLog as being delivered to the user because it wasn't - it was delivered to the spam mailbox

Comment: @Greg - fair enough, I didn't notice you answering your own Q. Perhaps you could elaborate a bit so that your Q&A have a bit more details then? For the next person that finds this via Google? Thanks!

Comment: @slm- fair point. I've updated the answer with some more details to try and make it more useful. Basically it was me not thinking